# VBA (Word): Draw Textbox with TextEffect msoTextEffectShapeArchUpCurve

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Summary:**

Using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), I'm trying to draw a Textbox and apply the TextEffect `msoTextEffectShapeArchUpCurve` to it.

This works fine when drawing this in an Excel sheet, but will not work in a Word document (although it can be done in the same way using the GUI).

So I have an Excel file where the script is run from. This script creates a new Word document and draws shapes inside of it.

**Example:**

```
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objDoc.Activate

    With ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        50, _
        50, _
        200, _
        200 _
    )
        .TextFrame.TextRange.text = "Some text to curve"
        .TextEffect.PresetShape = msoTextEffectShapeArchUpCurve '<-- error
    End With
```

**Problem:**

The code gives an `Error 4652: Invalid type of drawing object for this command`.
According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.texteffectformat.presetshape) this should work. (And it can be done with the GUI, although no code is produced when recording the actions in a macro..)

**Am I doing something wrong? And how can I fix this?**

***A screenshot of how it should look like (left) and how this is done in the GUI (right):***

[image]

Note: Using `AddTextEffect` instead of  `AddTextbox` is not really an option, since WordArt text is distorted compared to a textbox with the chosen effect.

Comment: Try `TextEffectFormat.PresetShape = msoTextEffectShapeArchUpCurve`

Comment: That gives a compile error. The `TextEffectFormat` object is returned from `.TextEffect` actually ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape.texteffect)).

Comment: That would make sense. Have you tried running this through the Macro Recorder?

Comment: Yes. No lines of code unfortunately.. (Only `ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 1")).Select`)

Comment: Yeah I thought so, word is a bit rubbish. Try changing archup to `msoTextEffectShapeChevronDown `, what happens now? That's from the example in the documentation

Comment: Same. It seems Word doesn't accept it when using VBA script, but only in GUI?

Comment: There's got to be a reason why. Try applying this to a regular shape, like in the example

Comment: The example sets the effect on a WordArt object, but I'm using a regular textbox. Which should work as the GUI handles that fine. Or are there some hidden steps performed that I'm missing?

Comment: Done a bit of research. Looks like this can only be via a Shape or CanvasItem. Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Thank you for the effort! Where did you find that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's **still a mystery** why Word won't let VBA set this text effect on textboxes, while on the other hand allowing it in the GUI. (Any help or information on that would still be greatly appreciated!)

However, there is a **work around** that worked for me:

1. Create the textbox in the Excel document and apply the text effect there (using the code from my example).
2. Then let VBA cut and paste the shape into the new Word document.

Answer (score 1):

You are using late binding (with CreateObject) so Excel does not know what `msoTextEffectShapeArchUpCurve` is.

It is a constant, a value, so you can just replace it with `9`.

Comment: Same result I'm afraid.. `Error 4652: Invalid type of drawing object for this command`

Comment: That is a completely different error, and it is quite clear.

Comment: True, but not in line with the official documentation and/or the GUI behaviour, so I'm a bit confused. Is it still possible to do this via VBA script?